# aws rekognition - issue with job id

Tags: amazon-rekognition

***EDIT: the issue is that there were items in the SQS queue that needed to be purged.*********

could you please help with an issue I am having?

I followed the steps in the URL below, but the first time I ran the Java code it failed and now I get this message every time the code runs:
"Job found was "f4ead620611a136a66826461377976d4467eee36dd9e06070bb96bd94b182a35"
Job received was not job 9390b07d024dde7065189d8f99399418de75da42142d919c65be32f1f15c0885"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/procedure-person-search-videos.html

Does anyone know how to kill/delete the "f4ead620611a136a66826461377976d4467eee36dd9e06070bb96bd94b182a35" job?

Comment: You should detail the steps you did here, rather than point to some random URL. After all, the people you are asking for help are *here*, and not at some random site.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that there were items in the SQS queue that needed to be purged.